# how to use Regexp_replace in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, regexp-replace

I am pretty new to spark and would like to perform an operation on a column of a dataframe so as to replace all the `,` in the column with `.`

Assume there is a dataframe x and column x4

```
x4
1,3435
1,6566
-0,34435
```

I want the output to be as

```
x4
1.3435
1.6566
-0.34435
```

The code I am using is

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
def replace = regexp_replace((x.x4,1,6566:String,1.6566:String)x.x4)
```

But I get the following error

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '.' found.
       def replace = regexp_replace((train_df.x37,0,160430299:String,0.160430299:String)train_df.x37)
```

Any help on the syntax, logic or any other suitable way would be much appreciated

Answer (score 34):

Here's a reproducible example, assuming `x4` is a string column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_replace

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1, "1,3435"),
  (2, "1,6566"),
  (3, "-0,34435"))).toDF("Id", "x4")
```

The syntax is `regexp_replace(str, pattern, replacement)`, which translates to:

```
df.withColumn("x4New", regexp_replace(df("x4"), "\\,", ".")).show
+---+--------+--------+
| Id|      x4|   x4New|
+---+--------+--------+
|  1|  1,3435|  1.3435|
|  2|  1,6566|  1.6566|
|  3|-0,34435|-0.34435|
+---+--------+--------+
```

Comment: can i use multiple characters in place of comma? for exmaple, i want to replace comma dot exclamation by any other char?

Comment: you want to replace multiple special characters by one character? yes it is possible.

Comment: I tried but didn't work. could you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: you could try something like `regexp_replace(df.col,  "[\\?,\\.,\\$]", "."))`

Answer (score -2):

We could use the `map` method to do this transformation:

```
scala> df.map(each => { 
(each.getInt(0),each.getString(1).replaceAll(",", "."))
})
.toDF("Id","x4")
.show

Output:

+---+--------+
| Id|      x4|
+---+--------+
|  1|  1.3435|
|  2|  1.6566|
|  3|-0.34435|
+---+--------+
```