# How to replace white space with comma in Spark ( with Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a log file like this. I want to create a DataFrame in Scala.

```
2015-05-13T23:39:43.945958Z my-loadbalancer 192.168.131.39:2817 10.0.0.1:80 0.000086 0.001048 0.001337 200 200 0 57 "GET https://www.example.com:443/ HTTP/1.1" "curl/7.38.0" DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1.2
```

I want to replace all the spaces with commas so that I can use spark.sql but I am unable to do so.

Here is everything I tried:

1. Tried importing it as text file first to see if there is a replaceAll method.
2. Tried splitting on the basis of space.

Any suggestions. I went through the documentation and there is no mention of replace function like in Pandas..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use Regexp\_replace in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080609/how-to-use-regexp-replace-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply tell spark that your delimiter is a white space like this:

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", " ").csv("path/to/file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have typed columns yet, I'd start as an RDD, split the text with a map then convert to a Dataframe with a schema. 
Roughly:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile({logline path}).map(line=>line.split("\\s+"))
```

Then you need to turn your RDD (where each record is an array of tokens) to a Dataframe. The most robust way would be to map your arrays to Row objects, as an RDD[Row] is what underlies a dataframe.

A simpler way to get up and going though would be

```
spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("datetime", "host", "ip", ...)
```

Comment: Almost precise. Thank you.

Comment: It is also replacing the space inside the quotes. Looking for a way to overcome it.

Comment: Now that I think of it, Spark dataframes have a CSV reader, it probably makes sense to just use that

Comment: Scala CSV reader: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@csv(paths:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: I want to use it but my dataset is a group of arrays, I mean each row is an array as shown in the above log. So I am looking to split everything based on space, give names to columns and then do SQL on it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @benlaird I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to split on space and retain the string within double quotes, you can use apache.commons.csv library.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser._
val str = """2015-05-13T23:39:43.945958Z my-loadbalancer 192.168.131.39:2817 10.0.0.1:80 0.000086 0.001048 0.001337 200 200 0 57 "GET https://www.example.com:443/ HTTP/1.1" "curl/7.38.0" DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1.2"""
val http = csv.CSVParser.parse(str,CSVFormat.newFormat(' ').withQuote('"')).getRecords.get(0).get(11)
val curl = csv.CSVParser.parse(str,CSVFormat.newFormat(' ').withQuote('"')).getRecords.get(0).get(12)
println(http)
println(curl)
```

Results:

```
GET https://www.example.com:443/ HTTP/1.1
curl/7.38.0
```